# Can I use a wildcard subdomain with my custom domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, wildcard-subdomain

Just checking to see if anyone knows if this is possible yet.  I would like to use a wildcard subdomain with firebase hosting and use functions to parse the subdomain.

Comment: This is a great idea!

Comment: waiting on this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, Firebase Hosting does not presently support wildcard subdomains. It's something that we'd like to do in the future, but there are no timelines or concrete plans to share at this time.

Comment: Hi @Michael, any update on this one? I can't find any in Google.

Comment: Answer stands -- still not possible, still something we'd like to do in the future.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Is there any alternative to this directly with Google Cloud, that could work with an existing Firebase setup?

Comment: Nothing off-the-shelf. You would need to run a reverse proxy and connect it up with your own wildcard domain, but doing so would largely remove the advantages of Firebase Hosting's global CDN delivery.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh is there any new update. Also we need this service.

Comment: Any update on this? Is there any chance to implement this feature?. Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking for a way to do this. Any idea?

Comment: Still something we'd like to support, but no timeline to announce.

Comment: even am looking for the same feature. Any update?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Any update on this?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thanks a lot for the answer and your updates in comments. Where can we open a proposal for this so that people see and up the proposal? I don't find any canny page for firebase, or repo to open a discussion or issue. Because I'm quite sure there're a lot of people who've seen your answer and didn't even bother up the question or your answer, so you can't realy know how much people are waiting for this feature.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh still waiting :( it's a shame that this level of customization isn't possible with google products :(